# Inject Custom class array using spring

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-mvc

I need to set an array of my custom class (XYZ[] xyz) in a bean using spring injection.
 
If this is an array of object i.e. (Object[] xyz), it works fine using list collection,
 but I get an exception when I change it to XYZ[] xyz.

Suggest what I need to do to accomplish this requirement.

```
Class ABC {
private XYZ[] xyzArray;
public void setXyzArray(XYZ[] xyz) {
this.xyz = xyz;
}
}


Class XYZ {
private string str;
public void setStr(String str) {
this.str = str;
}
}
```

Configuration XML:

```
<bean id="abc" class="com.test.ABC">
<property name="xyzArray">
<list>
<bean ref="xyz"/>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="xyz" class="com.test.XYZ">
<property name="str">
<value>Hello World</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

This xyzArray is not getting injected.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Some exception or xyzArray remains null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<array value-type="com.test.XYZ">
  <bean ref="xyz"/>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.xyz = xyz` should be `this.xyzArray = xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

That's becouse You have an error in xyzArray setter function. This shouldn't compile. 
Also try to keep Java naming standards for class name (should starts from upper letter followed by lower case).